# How to I crop multiple images in Python using x/y/r pixel coordinates in an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: python, pandas, image-processing, jupyter-notebook, crop

I am doing some image processing in python, and need to crop multiple areas within many thousands of images. The pixel coordinate data used to crop the ROI (region of interest) is in an Excel spreadsheet, and arranged as **THREE** comma seperated values within **ONE** column. As you can see from this [example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IM5f.png), there are multiple ROIs within *each* image that require cropping.

The three pixel coordinate values in this column are displayed as **[x,y,r]**, with the "x/y" coord values marking the *top left hand corner* of the square shaped ROI, and the "r" value representing the *length of each of the four sides* [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6Bkv.png) . Clearly, the way to find the ROI without multiple x/y values for each corner of the box is: "ROI = im[Y:Y+R, X:X+R]", however im struggling to get to this stage.

I have used the pandas.read_excel function to read in the spreadsheet, however im struggling to get any further? Can anyone help please?

Thanks, Rhod

Comment: You have already asked this question and I asked you to provide a realistic sample of the spreadsheet. You have now provided a *"picture"* of the spreadsheet which nobody can open in Excel. A picture also doesn't tell us if your spreadsheet is a CSV, an XLS or an XLSX file so you aren't helping yourself. Please provide a sample spreadsheet via Dropbox, or Google Drive or somesuch.Thank you.

Comment: My apologies, i felt my first question was unclear so wanted to refine it. You can find a sample of the data here: https://liveplymouthac-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/rhodri_irranca-davies_postgrad_plymouth_ac_uk/EtYvMXgn9hNOpWH0uYeoQ-cB3bULjN0BTwZLwuEpKZu5_g?e=gOegqU
(i have also included the first 5 images so you can see what the imagery looks like)

Comment: I think your problem will be easily solved if you break it down in a number of steps. Iterating through columns is easy with `pandas`. Expanding a list in `pandas` is a famous question on S/O. Cropping from x, y, and height/width has been done here a number of times too.

Comment: Yes pandas is a godsent. I'm managing to iterate through columns no problem, it's simply the cropping using the x/y/r method that I'm struggling with. Has it been answered? I couldn't find the question answered so it must have been my wording during my search. I will try and find it again. Cheers

Comment: what's wrong with the approach you mentioned? `ROI = im[Y:Y+R, X:X+R]`? I did that many times.

Comment: I'm struggling to apply that to data derived from a single spreadsheet column, opposed to three seperate columns. It's in the format: [1345.83,1738,44.26] ([x,y,r]). How do I attribute the three values to X, Y, and R?

Comment: I think it's with `pd.Series.explode()`. Once again, this is a small step and there are a lot of questions on that here.

Comment: Sorry I meant **cell** not column. 'pd.series.explode()' works for columns, but my three values are in the same cell in the format mentioned above, and this therefore doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Open spreadsheet
excel_file = 'spreadsheet.xlsx'
ss = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

# Extract filenames and coordinates
FandC = []
for index,row in ss.head().iterrows():
   filename = row['filename']
   coords   = row['Pixel coords']
   # Use regex to find anything that looks like a bunch of digits possibly with decimal point
   x, y, r = re.findall(r'[0-9.]+',coords)
   print(f'DEBUG: filename={filename}, x={x}, y={y}, r={r}')
   FandC.append({'filename': filename, 'x':x, 'y':y, 'r':r})
```

You now have a list of filenames and coordinates in `FandC` that looks like this:

```
DEBUG: filename=M116_13331848_13109013315679.jpg, x=1345.83, y=1738, r=44.26
DEBUG: filename=M116_13331848_13109013315679.jpg, x=776.33, y=698.17, r=65.72
DEBUG: filename=M116_13331848_13109013315679.jpg, x=1215.5, y=485.67, r=61.16
DEBUG: filename=M116_13331848_13109013315679.jpg, x=1439.33, y=502.67, r=64.73
DEBUG: filename=M116_13331848_13109013315679.jpg, x=793.33, y=1661.5, r=86.03
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly! Thank you so much Mark, and thanks also for your patience. I'm an ecologist stumbling around a programmers world, just (trying) to learn as I go :)

Comment: You're welcome. Come back and ask a new question if you get stuck - questions (and answers) are free Good luck with your project.